# JFrame FileChooser get file directory

Tags: java, swing, filechooser

I was doing an assignment. Basically the assignment is done but I was trying to make it better by adding a GUI to it.

But I was encountering some issue on `FileChooser` because I don't quite understand how it works.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CaesarCipherGui extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static JButton Encrypt  = new JButton("Encrypttion");
private static JButton Decrypt  = new JButton("Decrypttion");
private static JPanel  panel    = new JPanel();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new CaesarCipherGui();
}
private void addComponent(JPanel p, JComponent c, int x, int y, int width, int height, int align) {
    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gc.gridx = x;
    gc.gridy = y;
    gc.gridwidth = width;
    gc.gridheight = height;
    gc.weightx = 100.0;
    gc.weighty = 100.0;
    gc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    gc.anchor = align;
    gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    p.add(c, gc);
}

public CaesarCipherGui() {
    this.setSize(310, 192);
    this.setTitle("Caesar Cipher");
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(false);
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    addComponent(panel, Encrypt, 1, 4, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
    Encrypt.addActionListener(this);

    addComponent(panel, Decrypt, 1, 4, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.EAST);
    Decrypt.addActionListener(this);


    this.add(panel);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == Encrypt){
            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Input file: ");
            String inputFileName = console.next();
            System.out.print("Output file: ");
            String outputFileName = console.next();

            try{ 
                FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:/"+inputFileName+".txt");
                Scanner in = new Scanner(reader);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("C:/"+outputFileName+".txt");

                    while (in.hasNextLine()){
                        String line = in.nextLine();
                        String outPutText = "";
                        int key = 3;

                        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                            char c = line.charAt(i);
                            if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
                                c += key % 26;
                                if (c < 'a')
                                    c += 26;
                                if (c > 'z')
                                    c -= 26;
                            }
                            if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
                                c += key % 26;
                                if (c < 'A')
                                    c += 26;
                                if (c > 'Z')
                                    c -= 26;
                            }
                            if (c == ' '){
                                c = '#';
                            }
                            outPutText += c;
                        }
                        out.println(outPutText);

                    }
                    out.close();
                    }
            catch (IOException exception){
                System.out.println("Error processing file:" + exception);
            }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == Decrypt){
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input file: ");
        String inputFileName = console.next();
        System.out.print("Output file: ");
        String outputFileName = console.next();

        try{ 
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:/"+inputFileName+".txt");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(reader);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("C:/"+outputFileName+".txt");

                while (in.hasNextLine()){
                    String line = in.nextLine();
                    String outPutText = "";
                    int key = -3;

                    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                        char c = line.charAt(i);
                        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
                            c += key % 26;
                            if (c < 'a')
                                c += 26;
                            if (c > 'z')
                                c -= 26;
                        }
                        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
                            c += key % 26;
                            if (c < 'A')
                                c += 26;
                            if (c > 'Z')
                                c -= 26;
                        }
                        if (c == '#'){
                            c = ' ';
                        }
                        outPutText += c;
                    }
                    out.println(outPutText);

                }
                out.close();
                }
        catch (IOException exception){
            System.out.println("Error processing file:" + exception);
        }
}
}
}
```

As the code above is my assignment, but I wish to add the file chooser for the input filename and save file for the output filename, how am I gonna do it? Or you can just modify the part that needs to change and show me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, you add an actionlistener to a button and define the filechooser:

```
cmdSearch = new AbstractAction("Search", null) {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        txtSearch.setText( (fc.showOpenDialog(YOURCLASSNAME.this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) ? fc.getSelectedFile().toString() : txtSearch.getText() );                                    
    }
};
```

Comment: ok. i got this one. then how about the savedialog? is it the same way?

Comment: in principle yes, check the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html), posted above already...

Comment: thanks for the helps. now i am quite clear on the filechooser dialog now.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should start from the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html). Using a `JFileChooser` is quite easy, you just need to:

- show an open or save dialog according to what you are doing
- check the return value of the show function to see that the user effectively chose a file
- retrieve the `File` through `getSelectedFile()` method
- optionally use a custom `FileFilter` to let the user see just the file types you want

Comment: i saw that link. but what i want is that when i press the encrypt button, it will pop up the filechooser and then right after i select the file, then savedialog will prompt to save the file. so how to do that? is it i need to create another class?